# Is $e^{qz}=(e^z)^q$ true, with $z$ complex and $q\in\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, exponential-function, several-complex-variables

Is $e^{qz}=(e^z)^q$ true with $z$ complex and $q\in\mathbb{Q}$?

I've already proved it for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, but what about for $q\in\mathbb{Q}$? Is it true?

My proof for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$:
\begin{equation*}
 \begin{aligned}
 (e^z)^n=(e^xe^{iy})^n&=(e^x(\cos(y)+i\sin(y)))^n\\
 &=e^{nx}(\cos(y)+i\sin(y))^n\\
 &\overset{{\star}}{=}e^{nx}(\cos(ny)+i\sin(ny))\\
 &=e^{nx}e^{iny}=e^{n(x+iy)}\\
 &=e^{nz}. 
 \end{aligned}
 \end{equation*}
$\star$ By Moivre's Theorem for $|z|=1$.

Comment: LHS has  a unique value but RHS has infinitely many values.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I think I understand. But if I have
$$\sqrt[n]{|z^m|}\exp{\left(i\frac{1}{n} {\arg(z^m)}\right)},$$
with $\gcd(m,n)=1$, so can I conclude that
$$\sqrt[n]{|z^m|}\exp{\left(i\frac{1}{n} {\arg(z^m)}\right)}=\sqrt[n]{|z^m|}\exp{\left(i{\arg(z^m)}\right)}^{\frac{1}{n}}?$$

Comment: 1. The standard definitions of $e^z$ as single-valued (some authors write $\exp(z)$ to emphasise this choice) are unfortunately inconsistent with the general multi-valued definition of $w^z$ (where $w$ & $z$ are complex and $w$ nonzero): e.g., by the latter, $e^{\frac12}$ equals $\pm\sqrt{e}.$ So, if you rewrite your proof for $n\in\mathbb Z$ by replacing all the instances of $e$ with $\exp,$ then your result is indeed correct.

Comment: 2. However, when you replace the integer $n$ in your claim with rational $q,$ by our [previous discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4130288/21813), since $e^z$ here is just a general non-zero complex number, the new result becomes not generally true.