# The value of $i^{\frac{1}{2}}.$ Exponential of complex number.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, exponential-function

What the value of $i^{\frac{1}{2}}$ is ?

From the definition of exponential of complex numbers, I have $$i^{\frac{1}{2}}=e^{\frac{1}{2}\log i}.$$

And since $\log i=\log 1+\arg i =\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2}+2n\pi \right) i,$ I get
$i^{\frac{1}{2}}=e^{\frac{1}{2}(\frac{\pi}{2}+2n\pi) i}=e^{(\frac{\pi}{4}+n\pi) i}
=\cos(\frac{\pi}{4}+n\pi)  +i\sin(\frac{\pi}{4}+n\pi)=(-1)^n\cdot \dfrac{1+i}{\sqrt 2}.$

So, I get two values $\dfrac{1+i}{\sqrt 2}, -\dfrac{1+i}{\sqrt 2}.$

But according to wolfram alpha https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=i%5E%7B1%2F2%7D , $i^{\frac{1}{2}}=\dfrac{1+i}{\sqrt 2}.$

Is $-\dfrac{1+i}{\sqrt 2}$ a false value ? Do I overlook something about the definition of exponential of complex nubmers ?

Comment: Your work is correct.  This can be proven, based only on wolfram alpha, because you gave two answers: A-1, and A-2.  However, [1] wolfram alpha confirmed A-1 and [2] The square of the two answers must be identical, because $(-1)^2 = 1.$  Therefore, wolfram alpha has (in effect) confirmed your work.  It is probably a peculiarity of wolfram alpha that with $i = e^{i\pi/2}$, that it disfavors $e^{i5\pi/4}$ in favor of $e^{i\pi/4}.$

Comment: It could be that wolfram alpha has *extended* the Real Analysis convention that square roots are always positive to the Complex Analysis convention that is **sometimes** adopted that for the *principal* square root, the argument $(\theta)$ is always such that $\cos(\theta)$ is always non-negative.  Coupled with this convention is the convention that the *principal* $\sqrt{-1}$ is $(i)$, rather than $(-i)$.

Comment: In the WolframAlpha input field, [changing the braces to parentheses](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=i%5E%281%2F2%29) will give you both answers as desired. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4130288/21813) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4290262/21813) are my previous work on similar questions.

Answer (score -1):

let $i^{\frac {1} {2}}=a=\alpha+\beta i$, because we know that this form can represent all of the complex numbers. ($\alpha, \beta \geqslant0.$)

Then, $a^2=(\alpha^2-\beta^2)+2\alpha\beta i = i.$

We can easily get that $\alpha^2-\beta^2=0, 2\alpha\beta=1.$

So, $(\alpha, \beta)=\left( 
\dfrac {1} {\sqrt{2}}, \dfrac {1} {\sqrt{2}} \right)$.

Therefore, $i^{\frac {1} {2}}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\dfrac{i}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Comment: Why $\alpha,\beta \ge 0$?